# authentication in laravel customising the login redirection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an auth login page which logs in and redirects to home.blade.php

I need here to check whether user_type in user table is admin or Normal. If user_type=='admin' redirect to home else redirect to home_user page.

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/home_user', 'HomeController@index')->name('home_user');
```

or

```
protected function redirectTo() {
        if (Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin')
            return '/home';
        else
            return '/home_user';
    }
```

Comment: You can add a middleware for this purpose

Comment: middleware in routes i am new to laravel so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in the comment you can also use middleware but it could be the tricky way to do that. You can override the following function in the `loginController`.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
if (Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') {// do your magic here
    return redirect('/home');
}

 return redirect('/home_user');
}
```

For the reference you can visit [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/conditional-redirect-path-on-registerlogin)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199433/discussion-on-answer-by-zain-farooq-authentication-in-laravel-customising-the-lo).

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code, I have used for same. Try this.

 use Redirect;

 protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    if($user->is_admin == '1') {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }elseif ($user->is_admin == '2') {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('/admin/login');

    }else{
        return Redirect::to('studentDashboard');
    }

}
```

Comment: have you add  use Redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You have already solved the problem, but you have 1 mistake in your code.
In laravel in order to redirect, you need to return redirect()->to() or redirect()->route() functions. all you need to do is replace your code with this:

```
protected function redirectTo() {
        if (auth()->user()->user_type == 'admin')
            return redirect()->route('home');
        else
            return redirect()->route('home_user');
}
```

Comment: I am getting error Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Comment: @chaitra, where did you place this method(in which controller)?

Comment: in login contoller

Comment: Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/home_user', 'HomeController@index')->name('home_user'); i have given like this is it correct

Comment: both admin and normal going to same home page

Answer (score 0):

Override the existing `authenticated` method from `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

```
    /**
    * The user has been authenticated.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  mixed  $user
    * @return mixed
    */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin')
            return redirect('/home');
        else
            return redirect('/home_user');
    }
```

Reference: [`authenticated`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L105) method